# GCC: undefined reference - linker error

Tags: gcc, undefined-reference

I am trying to build a software package from source with make in Centos 6.5 which was successfully built in Fedora 8.
I made a few changes to the files and downgrade a few dependencies in Centos.
When I do make, I get a linker error:

```
/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/src/graphEdit.o: 
In function `GW::graphEdit::setPoints(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)': graphEdit.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `bool GW::GraphUtils::create<GW::MathVector<double, 3, GW::MathVectorColumn>
    >(GW::Graph<double, 3, GW::GraphColumn>&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char, char, char)' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked the gcc command initiated by make, it is:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -mfpmath=sse -finline-limit=1000   -shared -Xlinker --no-undefined   -Wl,-soname,libGraphImg.so
-o /home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/lib/graphImg.so /home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/src/graphType.o
/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/src/graphCalibration.o
/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/src/graphEdit.o
/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/src/imgMorph.o
-L/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/lib -Wl,
-rpath-link=/home/wjn/Desktop/samPro/lib -Wl,
-Bdynamic -lpthread -lm -lc
```

So I check graphUtils.h and graphUtils.cpp, bool GW::GraphUtils::create is properly defined but there is no graphUtils.o. 
It is perfectly built in Fedora 8, so I am guessing it is a compiler version problem?
Centos has GCC 4.4.7 and Fedora has 4.1.2, could this be the problem? What can I do to solve this if I don't want to use the old GCC to build it.

Comment: are the constructors defined in the `cpp` file? if so, move them into the header

Comment: The linked does not find graphUtils.o and therefore quits. You are likely have a compilation error before (try to do a `make clean && make` and check the output) or the Makefile is bad written (paste here the whole Makefile to let us check).